# Python console default hex display

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I'm doing a bunch of work in the Python console, and most of it is referring to addresses, which I'd prefer to see in hex.

So if `a = 0xBADF00D`, when I simply enter `Python> a` into the console to view its value, I'd prefer python to reply with `0xBADF00D` instead of `195948557`.

I know I can enter `'0x%X' % a` to see it in hex, but I'm looking for some sort of python console option to have it do this automatically.  Does something liket this exist? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But you can use `hex` to make the formatting more readable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The regular Python interpreter will call `sys.displayhook` to do the actual displaying of expressions you enter. You can replace it with something that displays exactly what you want, but you have to keep in mind that it is called for *all* expressions the interactive interpreter wants to display:

```
>>> import sys
>>> 1
1
>>> "1"
'1'
>>> def display_as_hex(item):
...     if isinstance(item, (int, long)):
...         print hex(item)
...     else:
...         print repr(item)
...
>>> sys.displayhook = display_as_hex
>>> 1
0x1
>>> "1"
'1'
```

I suspect you'll quickly get tired of seeing *all* integers as hex, though, and switch to explicitly converting the ones you want to see as hex accordingly.

Comment: Could print integers as both decimals *and* hex.

Comment: Adding a simple enahex() and dishex() to set, and restore the displayhook, respectively, allows one to go back and forth easily.  Thanks!

Comment: That is incredibly cool that you can override the way the prompt displays objects.  Nice answer

Answer (score 5):

Building on previous answers, here's a version that works for Python 2/3, doesn't display bools as hex, and also properly sets the `_` variable:

```
import sys

def _displayhook(o):
    if type(o).__name__ in ('int', 'long'):
        print(hex(o))
        __builtins__._ = o
    else:
        sys.__displayhook__(o)

def hexon():
    sys.displayhook = _displayhook
def hexoff():
    sys.displayhook=sys.__displayhook__
```

Comment: I had to remove the line `__builtins__._ = o`, since it would always throw `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_'`, but without that line it's working great.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
class HexInt(int):
    "Same as int, but __repr__() uses hex"

    def __repr__(self):
        return hex(self)
```

So you'd use that when creating all your integers that you want to be shown as hex values.

Example:

```
>>> a = HexInt(12345)
>>> b = HexInt(54321)
>>> a
0x3039
>>> b
0xd431
>>> c = HexInt(a + b)
>>> c
0x1046a
```

Note that if you wanted to skip the explicit creation of a new `HexInt` when doing arithmetic operations, you'd have to override the existing `int` versions of methods such as `__add__()`, `__sub__()`, etc., such that they'd return `HexInt`s.

Comment: I don't see how that's an improvement over just doing `hex(12345)` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the top python2 answer for python3...

```
def display_as_hex(item):
    if isinstance(item, int):
        print(hex(item))
    else:
        print(repr(item))
import sys
sys.displayhook = display_as_hex
```

Comment: Note, that will display `bool` as hex.

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this:

```
while True:
  print hex(input('> '))
```

To get a basic prompt that prints the hex value of all of the results. You could even make it conditional -- check to see if the return type of `input` is a string or number, and if it is, print the hex value, else print the value normally.

Comment: such answer.  very REPL. much useful.  wow.