# How to get hexadecimal notation in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The result in (interactive) python is in decimal notation

```
>>> 0xff
255
```

But I would like to see:

```
>>> 0xff
0xff
>>> 255
0xff
```

Can this be done?
(I know the hex function, or string formatting like '%x' %, but I would have the hexadecimal notation automatically).

Comment: @Corbellini Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from this post, this cannot be done by a simple setting.
Seems like you have to write some lines of code...

[Python console default hex display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307433/python-console-default-hex-display)